# How to implement history table with pure JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, history

I need to keep change of one "entity_name" into another log table called "entity_name_history" without using any JPA provider (I have to change existing project which doesn't use one). What I want to know is there anyway to implement history in pure JPA.

I have been looking into some persistent event intercept like @postUpdate, but from what I know I can't use entitymanager in those callback, if it can please tell me.

Comment: You do have a JPA provider. There's no such thing as 'pure jpa' - a provider is always required. Perhaps it is bundled in your application server?

Comment: @Bozho, I guess he means that he wants a solution that works with any JPA provider.

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich "which doesn't use one" led me to believe he thinks there is no provider.

Comment: @Bozho Is there a way to figure out what JPA provider using. From what I know it create through Eclipse Blue interface by New EJB Project (and I don't see any jpa provider selection there).

Comment: Are you using app server

Comment: I use glassfish on my dev env

Comment: I think glassfish comes bundled with EclipseLink

Comment: I try using history feature from http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/History, but it doesn't recognize the @Customize annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most clean solution is using database triggers to implement history feature.

Comment: my personal opinion is against database triggers, stored procedures and the likes. It its a maintenance problem usually.

Comment: well, I am also against database specific things, but this is a different case, the problem is well defined and the solution is very simple..

Comment: @Bozho we do almost all of our database access through stored procedures which also update the history table. That's why we have database developers in the team. I personally feel that gives a nice extra interface layer to the software comparable to our other data sources (like soap services). But triggers just for this might indeed be troublesome in maintenance.

Comment: The question was how to implement with pure JPA.

Answer (score 1):

There is an abundant litterature about that subject, although it's usually called "entity auditing". Hibernate provides a module, called [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers), specially built for that, and obviously using that kind of JPA triggers.

There is also a (good?) tutorial on [implementing it using TopLink](http://java-persistence.blogspot.com/2007/04/simple-auditing-using-toplink-jpa.html) (now EclipseLink).

So, yes, that's the way to do, but, no, you shouldn't do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be used, just it has to be used with care. Here is quote from JPA specification:

> In general, portable applications should not invoke EntityManager or Query operations,
>   access other entity instances, or modify relationships in a lifecycle callback method.

As an alternative you can use different entity manager or use pure JDBC data source connection that will live in the same transaction. Especially, if you don't need to do any manipulations with your history objects in the same JPA session.